# Python Tornado send WebSocket messages from another thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio, tornado

I want to use WebSockets in Python to keep web clients up to date about data that I am reading from a serial port using PySerial. I am currently using the following code to read the serial data in continuously with a separate thread

```
def read_from_port():
    while running:
        reading = ser.readline().decode()
        handle_data(reading)

thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_port)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

I am performing some processing on the serial data and then want to broadcast a message to all the connected WebSocket clients if the calculated result differs from its previous value. For this I have set up the following code

```
clients = []

def Broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.sendMessage(json.dumps(message).encode('utf8'))
        print("broadcasted")

worker.broadcast = Broadcast

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('new connection')
        clients.append(self)
      
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('message received:  %s' % message)
        response = handler.HandleRequest(message, self.write_message)
 
    def on_close(self):
        print('connection closed')
        clients.remove(self)
 
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
 
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8765)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print('*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I then want to use the "broadcast" method in the worker to broadcast out a result. Using this method from the worker thread produces the following error

```
File "main.py", line 18, in Broadcast
    client.write_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 342, in write_message
    return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1098, in write_message
    fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1075, in _write_frame
    return self.stream.write(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 555, in write
    future = Future()  # type: Future[None]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

I understand the issue is that the Tornado write_message function is not thread safe and that this error is being produced because I am trying to call the function directly from the worker thread. As far as I can determine, the recommended way to use concurrent code with Tornado is through asyncio, but I think a threading approach might be more appropriate in this situation where I have a loop that essentially runs in parallel constantly.

Unfortunately I know very little about asyncio and how threading is implemented in Python, so I would like to find out what is the simplest way that I can send WebSocket messages from a different thread.

Comment: Just a note, it's a bad idea to write method or function names with a capital first letter, because then it is difficult to understand if the name is a class or a function. The convention is to use capitalized names for classes and lowercase for functions.

Comment: Multithreading in Python is just fine. The problem is these horrible web server software packages. Yes, the above code fails -- sometimes the iostream is written from the calling thread, sometimes from an "event loop". So assertions fail in the iostream. The whole thing is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the official documentation for using asyncio and multithreading together at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading gave me the necessary clue that one can achieve this quite elegantly using the "call_soon_threadsafe" function. The following code thus seems to do the trick

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure("tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop")
io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
asyncio.set_event_loop(io_loop.asyncio_loop)

clients = []

def bcint(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.write_message(message)
        print("broadcasted")

def Broadcast(message):
    io_loop.asyncio_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(bcint, message)

worker.broadcast = Broadcast

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('new connection')
        clients.append(self)
      
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('message received:  %s' % message)
        response = handler.HandleRequest(message, self.write_message)
 
    def on_close(self):
        print('connection closed')
        clients.remove(self)
 
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
 
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8765)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print('*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'. Maybe your answer is assuming Python 3? The question did not say Python 3.

Comment: @personal_cloud Python2 reached end-of-life in 2020.

Comment: @Jeppe Yes. The Python Foundation is giving up on Python2, Fortran, and various other languages. That's all fine and good. However, Python3 is still not compatible with basic Python2 features such as bytestring and print syntax. So all of the software written in Python2 remains in Python2. This software must be maintained and improved in Python2. Much as Fortran, Modula-3, etc. software is still maintained in its original language, regardless of how "dead" the language is pronounced.

Comment: My point is, you should always assume python3 unless otherwise stated. The code included in this answer and the original post, is python3.

Answer (score 0):

One cleaner option is to use queues such as [pyzmq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Multithreading-with-ZeroMQ) that will help you establish communication from one thread to another.

Looking at your use case, you can use PUB/SUB model. Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples/asyncio). Also, you can use 'inproc' instead of 'tcp'. This will reduce the latency since you will be communicating between multiple threads in same process.