# Python 2.7 Tornado 5.1.1 send WebSocket messages from another thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tornado

I have the latest tornado for Python2.7. I am using it as a websocket server. Since it calls itself an "asynchronous networking library" (see below), it is natural to assume that one can send messages asynchronously. How do I actually do that?

```
 pip show tornado
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: tornado
Version: 5.1.1
Summary: Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library, originally developed at FriendFeed.
Home-page: http://www.tornadoweb.org/
Author: Facebook
Author-email: python-tornado@googlegroups.com
```

[This question has been asked for Python 3 already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052350/python-tornado-send-websocket-messages-from-another-thread) My question is about Python2.7. The Python3 solution (`tornado.ioloop.asyncio_loop.call_soon_threadsafe`)  does not work in Python2.7:

```
    tornado.ioloop.asyncio_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(Send, srv, msg)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'
```

I also tried the `add_callback` function because there are comments in other functions that say "use `add_callback` to transfer control to the IOLoop's thread" which sounds like exactly what I want... but it doesn't seem to do anything (my callback isn't called.)

I also tried simply calling `write_message` with a mutex lock, or even *from the same thread every time*, but this doesn't work: `tornado` occassionally (and only under moderate load) calls the `iostream` from the main thread ("event loop") and corrupts it by accessing it concurrently without a lock.

What is the function to safely schedule asynchronous events in the Python2.7 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my problem. The `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()` needs to be called only once, and the value saved. This same value needs to be used for `start()` and `add_callback()`.

(But then if the basic IOLoop already enables asynchronous events, then why are people using the `asyncio_loop` module in newer versions? Something is suspicious about this software package. It seems very complicated.)

Comment: And how can I observe after its changed to 6.0 version it has a lot of problems with backward compatibility and compatibility with some solutions.